# Error when renaming image name on VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I am using VirtualBox. I want to change the name of my VM from `Ubuntu 15.04` to `Ubuntu 16.04`. I went to the settings to change the name but encountered the error below;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log in to your Administrator account on windows. Then, launch Vbox manager by right clicking and choosing "Run as administrator"